# Ошибка при создании нового проекта после команды rails new

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Возникает ошибка (1 скрин) после команды создания нового Rails проекта, подскажите с чем это может быть связано. Как я понял, нужно установить переменную HOME, но она вроде как установлена (2 скрин)
[image: Код ошибки]

[image: Насколько я понял, ошибка связана с переменной HOME, но она вроде как установлена...]

Comment: Рекомендую не заниматься Rails на Windows. Это боль со многих сторон. В этом случае, подозреваю, проблема в кириллице внутри пути, но это догадка, которую я сейчас не могу проверить.

Comment: Автор, virtualbox и ubuntu решают 99% проблем начинающих windows-рубистов. В любом случае *nix системы нужно знать -- все сервера обычно под линупсом.

Comment: @PavelVolzhin да проблема была действительно в кириллице, пришлось переименовывать папку юзера :